# sqlmap load https request using "-r REQUESTFILE Load HTTP request from a file"

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I'm testing a site that automatically redirects http request to https. When I'm using Burp I set the target to use https and the request goes through without a problem. However when I use the same request in sqlmap I get a follow redirect. How can I set the requestfile to use https?

Command:

```
C:\Users\Oscar\Desktop\sqlmap-master>python sqlmap.py -r testsite.txt --level=5 risk=3 -p id
```

Host:

```
GET /user?id=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.testsite.com
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found two possible solutions from https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage.

`--force-ssl`:

```
C:\Users\Oscar\Desktop\sqlmap-master>python sqlmap.py -r testsite.txt --level=5 risk=3 --force-ssl -p id
```

Host:

```
GET /user?id=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.testsite.com:443
```

Comment: I guess it achieves the same effect if you rewrite your urls to include https